# How to add radio button in menu bar, qt 5 c++

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a QT GUI based application for demonstration of some algorithms, I want to select one algorithm at a time from menu bar.

for this I have two approaches in mind,

one is to make QAction checkable and loop through each and check only one which is clicked and uncheck all the others.

the other is to add radio button in menubar.

which approach is more better ?

If second one is better how do I do that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [QActionGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qactiongroup.html) and use `setExclusive(true)` which will allow only one checkable `QAction` to be checked at a time, so you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: You saved my time :-), Thanks @Rostislav

Comment: The QAction group cannot be added from the Qt Designer. It needs to be added to the .ui xml file manually. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191890/qt-qactiongroup-with-qaction-in-toolbar