# Qt QActionGroup with QAction in toolbar

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a QActionGroup with QAction buttons in a Toolbar made within the Designer mode.

The goal is to make only one button being clicked. I followed this  example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qactiongroup.html#details but it doesn't make my buttons exclusive.
I also tried to force
 `alignmentGroup.setExclusive(true);`

mainwindow.cpp, in MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)

```
        alignmentGroup.addAction(ui->actionUsePointer);
        alignmentGroup.addAction(ui->actionMoveView);
        alignmentGroup.addAction(ui->actionEditText);
        ui->actionUsePointer->setChecked(true);
```

[my ui designer objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St0EI.png)

I followed the example but when I click on actionUsePointer for example, i can check all buttons without uncheck the first one...

**EDIT**
Here is the mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1098</width>
    <height>815</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>FSM Editor</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
      <item>
       <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color:grey;</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="textBrowser">
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>300</width>
           <height>16777215</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1098</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="nativeMenuBar">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFichier">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Fichier</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionOuvrir"/>
    <addaction name="actionR_cemment_ouvert"/>
    <addaction name="actionEnregistrer"/>
    <addaction name="actionEnregistrer_sous"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menu_dition">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Édition</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionAnnuler"/>
    <addaction name="actionRevenir"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuBackground">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Background</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionAucun"/>
    <addaction name="actionQuadrillage"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFichier"/>
   <addaction name="menu_dition"/>
   <addaction name="menuBackground"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="toolBar">
   <property name="windowTitle">
    <string>toolBar</string>
   </property>
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
   <addaction name="actionUsePointer"/>
   <addaction name="actionMoveView"/>
   <addaction name="actionEditText"/>
   <addaction name="separator"/>
   <addaction name="actionShowEditor"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionOuvrir">
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/img/folder-open.png</normaloff>:/img/folder-open.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Ouvrir...</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionR_cemment_ouvert">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Récemment ouvert</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionEnregistrer">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Enregistrer</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionEnregistrer_sous">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Enregistrer sous</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionAnnuler">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Annuler</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionRevenir">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Revenir</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionUsePointer">
   <property name="checkable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="enabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/img/mouse-pointer.png</normaloff>:/img/mouse-pointer.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>UsePointer</string>
   </property>
   <property name="iconVisibleInMenu">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionMoveView">
   <property name="checkable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/img/arrows.png</normaloff>:/img/arrows.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>moveView</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionEditText">
   <property name="checkable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
     <normaloff>:/img/i-cursor.png</normaloff>:/img/i-cursor.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>EditText</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionAucun">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Aucun</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionQuadrillage">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Quadrillage</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionShowEditor">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Afficher l'XML</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="icons.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**EDIT 2 :**
I'm not crazy, the action group feature is really missing from the Form Editor where it should be : https://forum.qt.io/topic/27282/qt-creator-2-7-x-creating-action-groups-in-form-editor/2

Comment: Your question is not complete. If you would have posted a [complete Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you would had added how you created the `alignmentGroup` in there one would see that its probably how you setup that group, i.e. missing `QActionGroup::ExclusionPolicy::Exclusive`. And no `ui->actionUsePointer->setChecked(true); ` doesn't count since we don't know who `ui` is

Comment: Actually you're right I'm new and not very good at writing this kind of post. I'll improve.The ui is a big .xml file created by Qt Designer editor

Comment: I'm not crazy, the action group is really missing from the Form Editor as it should be : https://forum.qt.io/topic/27282/qt-creator-2-7-x-creating-action-groups-in-form-editor/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem with this : 
https://forum.qt.io/topic/27282/qt-creator-2-7-x-creating-action-groups-in-form-editor/3

It's seems that the GUI Qt Editor doesn't allow to add ActionGroup visually so you have to touch the raw .xml ui.

I opened the mainwindow.ui with a text editor instead of the graphic editor and created the ActionGroup inside (i called it GroupTool) with all my actions inside

```
<actiongroup name="GroupTool">
   <action name="actionUsePointer">
    <property name="checkable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
      <normaloff>:/img/mouse-pointer.png</normaloff>:/img/mouse-pointer.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>UsePointer</string>
    </property>
    <property name="autoRepeat">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="iconVisibleInMenu">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </action>
   <action name="actionMoveView">
    <property name="checkable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
      <normaloff>:/img/arrows.png</normaloff>:/img/arrows.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>moveView</string>
    </property>
   </action>
   <action name="actionEditText">
    <property name="checkable">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="icon">
     <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
      <normaloff>:/img/i-cursor.png</normaloff>:/img/i-cursor.png</iconset>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>EditText</string>
    </property>
   </action>
  </actiongroup>
```

and finaly in the mainwindow.cpp :

```
ui->GroupTool->setExclusive(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The example linked in the question is most of it, with a small tweak needed for using the form from Qt Designer.

The trick is that you can add actions to a QActionGroup after the actions have been created by Qt Designer.

In the form header file (mainwindow.h), add a :
QActionGroup *groupTool;

In the MainWindow constructor, where you are connecting signals/slots, create the action group, add the actions to it, and set it exclusive:

```
groupTool = new QActionGroup(this);
groupTool.addAction(ui->actionUsePointer);
...
groupTool.setExclusive(true);
```

In Qt Designer:

- set the checkable property to true for each of the actions
- set the checked property to true for one of the actions